# Cumulative number of files in subfolders

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I do have a table with list of files. There is id_folder, id_parrent_folder, size (file size):

```
create table sample_data (
    id_folder bigint ,
    id_parrent_folder bigint,
    size bigint
);
```

I would like to know, how many files are in every subfolder (including current folder) for each folder (starting wigh given folder). Given the samle data posted below I expect the following output:

```
id_folder     files
100623           35
100624           14
```

Sample data:

```
insert into sample_data values (100623,58091,60928);
insert into sample_data values (100623,58091,59904);
insert into sample_data values (100623,58091,54784);
insert into sample_data values (100623,58091,65024);
insert into sample_data values (100623,58091,25600);
insert into sample_data values (100623,58091,31744);
insert into sample_data values (100623,58091,27648);
insert into sample_data values (100623,58091,39424);
insert into sample_data values (100623,58091,30720);
insert into sample_data values (100623,58091,71168);
insert into sample_data values (100623,58091,68608);
insert into sample_data values (100623,58091,34304);
insert into sample_data values (100623,58091,46592);
insert into sample_data values (100623,58091,35328);
insert into sample_data values (100623,58091,29184);
insert into sample_data values (100623,58091,38912);
insert into sample_data values (100623,58091,38400);
insert into sample_data values (100623,58091,49152);
insert into sample_data values (100623,58091,14444);
insert into sample_data values (100623,58091,33792);
insert into sample_data values (100623,58091,14789);
insert into sample_data values (100624,100623,16873);
insert into sample_data values (100624,100623,32768);
insert into sample_data values (100624,100623,104920);
insert into sample_data values (100624,100623,105648);
insert into sample_data values (100624,100623,31744);
insert into sample_data values (100624,100623,16431);
insert into sample_data values (100624,100623,46592);
insert into sample_data values (100624,100623,28160);
insert into sample_data values (100624,100623,58650);
insert into sample_data values (100624,100623,162);
insert into sample_data values (100624,100623,162);
insert into sample_data values (100624,100623,162);
insert into sample_data values (100624,100623,162);
insert into sample_data values (100624,100623,162);
```

I've tried to use example from postgresql ([postgresql docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html)), but it (obviously) can't work this way. Any help appreciated.

-- Edit

I've tried the following query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE included_files(id_folder, parrent_folder, dist_last_change) AS (
SELECT 
    id_folder, 
    id_parrent_folder, 
    size
FROM 
    sample_data p 
WHERE 
    id_folder = 100623
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    p.id_folder, 
    p.id_parrent_folder, 
    p.size
FROM 
    included_files if, 
    sample_data p
WHERE 
    p.id_parrent_folder = if.id_folder
)
select * from included_files
```

This won't work, because for every child there is a lot of parents and as a result rows in child folders are multiplied.

Comment: even though it's not the quickest solution, but have you tried using a cursor?

Comment: +1 for supplying test data and create table statements

Comment: @FlorisPrijt I did not - honestly, I do not understand how this would help in solving my problem.

Comment: Your sample data seems strange. Why do you have multiple entries with the same combination of `id_folder` and `id_parrent_folder`? That doesn't make sense to me. (btw. parent is spelled only with one r: it should be `id_parent_folder`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry for typo in "parent" Data are in this way because I do have list of files. In every folder there can unlimited number of files.

Comment: How is a folder containing only folders and no files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very nice problem to think about, I upvoted!

As I see it, 2 cases to think about:

1. multi-level paths and
2. multi-child nodes.

So far I've came up with the following query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (
    SELECT id_folder id, array[id_folder] arr
      FROM sample_data sd
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sample_data s
                        WHERE s.id_parrent_folder=sd.id_folder)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT sd.id_folder,t.arr||sd.id_folder
      FROM tree t
      JOIN sample_data sd ON sd.id_folder IN (
        SELECT id_parrent_folder FROM sample_data WHERE id_folder=t.id))
,ids AS (SELECT DISTINCT id, unnest(arr) ua FROM tree)
,agg AS (SELECT id_folder id,count(*) cnt FROM sample_data GROUP BY 1)
SELECT ids.id, sum(agg.cnt)
  FROM ids JOIN agg ON ids.ua=agg.id
 GROUP BY 1
 ORDER BY 1;
```

I've added the following rows to the `sample_data`:

```
INSERT INTO sample_data VALUES (100625,100623,123);
INSERT INTO sample_data VALUES (100625,100623,456);
INSERT INTO sample_data VALUES (100625,100623,789);
INSERT INTO sample_data VALUES (100626,100625,1);
```

This query is not optimal though and will be slowing down as number of rows grows.

---

**Full-scale tests**

In order to simulate original situation, I've done a small python script that scans filesystem and stores it into the database (thus the delay, I'm not yet good at python scripting).

The following tables had been created:

```sql
CREATE TABLE fs_file(file_id bigserial, name text, type char(1), level int4);
CREATE TABLE fs_tree(file_id int8, parent_id int8, size int8);
```

Scanning whole filesystem of my MBP took 7.5 minutes and I have 870k entries in the `fs_tree` table, which is quite similar to the original task. After upload, the following was run:

```sql
CREATE INDEX i_fs_tree_1 ON fs_tree(file_id);
CREATE INDEX i_fs_tree_2 ON fs_tree(parent_id);
VACUUM ANALYZE fs_file;
VACUUM ANALYZE fs_tree;
```

I've tried running my first query on this data and had to kill it after aprx 1 hour. The improved one takes round 2 minutes (on my MBP) to do the job on the *whole* filesystem. Here it comes:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE descent AS (
    SELECT fs.file_id grp, fs.file_id, fs.size, 1 k, 0 AS lvl
      FROM fs_tree fs
     WHERE fs.parent_id = (SELECT file_id FROM fs_file WHERE name = '/')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN k.k=0 THEN d.grp ELSE fs.file_id END AS grp,
           fs.file_id, fs.size, k.k, d.lvl+1
      FROM descent d
      JOIN fs_tree fs ON d.file_id=fs.parent_id
      CROSS JOIN generate_series(0,1) k(k))
/* the query */
SELECT grp, file_id, size, k, lvl
  FROM descent
 ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

Query uses my table names, but it shouldn't be difficult to change it. It will build a set of groups for each `file_id` found in the `fs_tree`. To get the desired output, you can do something like:

```sql
SELECT grp AS file_id, count(*), sum(size)
  FROM descent GROUP BY 1;
```

Some notes:

1. query will work *only* if there're no duplicates. I think it is a right way to go, 'cos it is impossible to have 2 equally named entries in a single directory;
2. query doesn't care bout the depth or sibling count of the tree, though this does have impact on the performance;
3. for me it was good experience, as similar functionality is needed also for task planning systems (I'm working with one at the moment);
4. as tasks are considered, single entry can have multiple parents (but not otherwise) and query will still work;
5. this problem can be solved in other ways too, like traversing the tree in ascending order, or using pre-calculated values to avoid the final grouping step, but this is getting a bit bigger then a simple question, so I live it as an exercise for you.

**Recommendations**

To get this query work, you should prepare your data by aggregating it:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
fs_tree AS (
    SELECT id_folder file_id, id_parrent_folder parent_id,
           sum(size) AS size, count(*) AS cnt
      FROM sample_data GROUP BY 1,2)
,descent AS (
    SELECT fs.file_id grp, fs.file_id, fs.size, fs.cnt, 1 k, 0 AS lvl
      FROM fs_tree fs
     WHERE fs.parent_id = 58091
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN k.k=0 THEN d.grp ELSE fs.file_id END AS grp,
           fs.file_id, fs.size, fs.cnt, k.k, d.lvl+1
      FROM descent d
      JOIN fs_tree fs ON d.file_id=fs.parent_id
      CROSS JOIN generate_series(0,1) k(k))
/* the query */
SELECT grp file_id, sum(size) size, sum(cnt) cnt
  FROM descent
 GROUP BY 1
 ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

In order to speed things up, you can implement [Materialized Views](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Materialized_Views) and pre-calculate some metrics.

---

**Sample data**

Here's a small dump that will show the data inside the tables:

```sql
INSERT INTO fs_file VALUES (1, '/Users/viy/prj/logs', 'D', 0),
    (2, 'jobs', 'D', 1),
    (3, 'pg_csv_load', 'F', 2),
    (4, 'pg_logs', 'F', 2),
    (5, 'logs.sql', 'F', 1),
    (6, 'logs.sql~', 'F', 1),
    (7, 'pgfouine-1.2.tar.gz', 'F', 1),
    (8, 'u.sql', 'F', 1),
    (9, 'u.sql~', 'F', 1);

INSERT INTO fs_tree VALUES (1, NULL, 0),
    (2, 1, 0),
    (3, 2, 936),
    (4, 2, 706),
    (5, 1, 4261),
    (6, 1, 4261),
    (7, 1, 793004),
    (8, 1, 491),
    (9, 1, 491);
```

**Note**, that I've slightly updated create statements.

And this is the script I've used to scan the filesystem:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import psycopg2
import sys
from stat import *

def walk_tree(full, parent, level, call_back):
    '''recursively descend the directory tree rooted at top,
       calling the callback function for each regular file'''

    if not os.access(full, os.R_OK):
        return

    for f in os.listdir(full):
        path = os.path.join(full, f)
        if os.path.islink(path):
            # It's a link, register and continue
            e = entry(f, "L", level)
            call_back(parent, e, 0)
            continue

        mode = os.stat(path).st_mode
        if S_ISDIR(mode):
            e = entry(f, "D", level)
            call_back(parent, e, 0)
            # It's a directory, recurse into it
            try:
                walk_tree(path, e, level+1, call_back)
            except OSError:
                pass

        elif S_ISREG(mode):
            # It's a file, call the callback function
            call_back(parent, entry(f, "F", level), os.stat(path).st_size)
        else:
            # It's unknown, just register
            e = entry(f, "U", level)
            call_back(parent, e, 0)

def register(parent, entry, size):
    db_cur.execute("INSERT INTO fs_tree VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",
                   (entry, parent, size))

def entry(name, type, level):
    db_cur.execute("""INSERT INTO fs_file(name,type, level)
                   VALUES (%s, %s, %s) RETURNING file_id""",
                   (name, type, level))
    return db_cur.fetchone()[0]

db_con=psycopg2.connect("dbname=postgres")
db_cur=db_con.cursor()

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    raise SyntaxError("Root directory expected!")

if not S_ISDIR(os.stat(sys.argv[1]).st_mode):
    raise SyntaxError("A directory is wanted!")

e=entry(sys.argv[1], "D", 0)
register(None, e, 0)
walk_tree(sys.argv[1], e, 1, register)

db_con.commit()

db_cur.close()
db_con.close()
```

This script is for Python 3.2 and is based on the example from [official python documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/stat.html).

Hope this clarifies things for you.

Comment: This does the job, great! Please let us know if you can improve performance of this query. I do have a table with 1,000,000 rows (files) :/ What I would like to do is something like [JDiskReport](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jdiskreport/) can do.

Comment: @twn08, having duplicate entries gives a real headache here, I have to  add artificial keys.

Comment: thank you for your hard work. Can you please add few rows with sample data to the answer? It seems I do not fully understand what is in fs_file / fs_tree folder and how those two are related.

Comment: @twn08, sample data and script added ツ

Answer (score 2):

With your sample data, this returns what you want. I'm not 100% sure though that it will cover all possible anomalies in your tree:

```
with recursive folder_sizes as (
   select id_folder, id_parent_folder, count(*) as num_files
   from sample_data
   group by id_folder, id_parent_folder
), 
folder_tree as (

   select id_folder, id_parent_folder, num_files as total_files
   from folder_sizes
   where id_parent_folder = 100623

   union all 

   select c.id_folder, c.id_parent_folder, c.num_files + p.total_files as total_files
   from folder_sizes c
     join folder_tree p on p.id_parent_folder = c.id_folder

)
select id_folder, id_parent_folder, total_files
from folder_tree;
```

Here is a SQLFiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/bb942/2

This only covers a single level hierarchy though (because of the `id_parent_folder = 100623` condition). To cover any number of levels, I can only think of a two step approach, that first collects all sub-folders and then walks that tree up again, to calculate the total number of files.

Something like this:

```
with recursive folder_sizes as (
   select id_folder, id_parent_folder, count(*) as num_files
   from sample_data
   group by id_folder, id_parent_folder
), 
folder_tree_down as (
   select id_folder, id_parent_folder, num_files, id_folder as root_folder, 1 as level
   from folder_sizes

   union all 

   select c.id_folder, c.id_parent_folder, c.num_files, p.root_folder, p.level + 1 as level
   from folder_sizes c
     join folder_tree_down p on p.id_folder = c.id_parent_folder
), 
folder_tree_up as (

   select id_folder, id_parent_folder, num_files as total_files, level
   from folder_tree_down
   where root_folder = 100623

   union all 

   select c.id_folder, c.id_parent_folder, c.num_files + p.total_files as total_files, p.level
   from folder_tree_down c
     join folder_tree_up p on p.id_parent_folder = c.id_folder

)
select id_folder, id_parent_folder, total_files
from folder_tree_up
where level > 1;
```

That produces the same output as the first statement, but I *think* it should work with an unlimited number of levels.

Comment: As you already figured out, I'm interested in solving this for multiple levels. To cover this case, I've prepared better sample data on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/a1d24/2/0). I've used solution provided by vyegorov, however I'm not sure it will work on 1,000,000 rows table. Please let us know, if you can come up with better performing query.